# Rings with zero divisors in which $x^2=x$ implies $x\in\{0,1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

Any idempotent element (other than 0 or 1) must be a zero-divisor, so in particular there are no nontrivial idempotents in domains.

> Are there examples of rings with zero divisors without nontrivial idempotents? (If so, is there anything interesting to say about such rings, e.g., characterizations?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Quotient rings $\Z/p^{n}\Z$, with $p$ a prime, have zero divisors for $n \ge 2$, but no idempotents $\ne 0, 1$. As noted in another answer, more generally local rings have no non-trivial idempotents.

Answer (score 4):

You may find this interesting. To each ring $A$ we may attach a geometric space $\text{Spec } A$. For instance, if the ring is of the form $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/f(x,y)$ you may picture this space as the graph of the equation $f(x,y) = 0$ (although you have to pretend that $\mathbb{C}$ looks like $\mathbb{R}$ to draw this graph on paper).

A ring has a non-trivial idempotent if and only if this space is disconnected. It has a zero-divisor which is not nilpotent if and only if this space is "reducible" (google it for the formal definition, but the idea is that it looks like a union of two spaces meeting in a space of smaller dimension).

From this we can get many examples. For instance, $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(xy)$. This looks like the union of two lines meeting at the origin. Contrast a ring with idempotents, e.g. $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x^2 - x)$ which looks like the disjoint union of two vertical lines.

Comment: I swear I just saw your answer! Upvoting you because great minds think alike... :)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Do you mean "great and *modest*"? just kidding...

Answer (score 3):

Idempotents of $R$ correspond to clopen subsets of $X = \text{Spec } R$. When $R$ is noetherian, a clopen subset is necessarily a finite disjoint union of connected components.

On the other hand, zero divisors of $R$ correspond to closed subsets of $X$ whose complement is contained in a proper closed subset of $R$. When $R$ is noetherian, such a closed subset is a finite, nonempty union of irreducible components.

Thus, we can obtain a wide variety of examples from geometry. Whenever $X$ is connected but not irreducible, $R$ has nontrivial zero divisors but no nontrival idempotents. For instance, the variety consisting of two intersecting lines is connected but not irreducible, so the ring $\mathbf C[x,y]/(xy)$ has nontrivial zero divisors (eg. $x$ and $y$!) but no nontrivial idempotents.

Answer (score 0):

One example: $\mathbb{Z}_2$, or more generally, $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ for prime $p$ and integer $n$.

In this instance, all zero divisors are nilpotent (of order at most $n$).